# Netbeans error: Project Folder already exists and is not empty

Tags: netbeans, project

I installed Netbeans , because I am reading the book : Java in 21 days. I'm a complete novice in the world of programming. When I try to open a new project in Netbeans , I get the error : *Project Folder already exists and is not empty* . Deleting the nbproject folder and restarting the IDE doesn't solve this problem. Can anybody help me?

Comment: In order to create a project you have to give a name for the project and a folder where the project should be created. What values are you using? Have you tried using a different name for the project? Have you tried reading the basic tutorial in Netbeans page?

Answer (score 1):

I have NetBeans 7.3.1 installed on a mac (10.8.4) and it works flawlessly. I do recall having a similar issue, however, when trying to create a project into a directory I thought was empty (it wasn't...). For me it was just a matter of deleting the project directory. For you, I found the same answer while Googling as @striders. If you are using mac, there won't be a ".netbeans" folder containing the "userdir"; rather, the directory is `~/Library/Application\ Support/NetBeans/7.2`. I understand "7.2" to be the "userdir". So if the solution is to have NetBeans recreate this directory, simply delete it and relaunch. I tested the deletion of this folder, and NetBeans does create it on start up.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir (info on the directory...)

http://forums.netbeans.org/post-59080.html (someone said this worked...)

Cheers